# How to get the wildcard matched portion from a filename

Tags: shell

```
for name in file*.txt
do
   echo ${name%.txt} | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'
done
```

is there a better way then using grep? I have file1.txt, file2.txt ...., want to extract just the numbers.

Comment: BTW, if you have a file created with `touch 'file hello * world.txt'`, you'll get some unusual output (because `echo ${name%.txt}` will expand the `*`, replacing it with a list of other files in the current directory). Quotes matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shell is bash, you might also consider replacing all non-numeric characters with the empty string with a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), as follows:

```
for name in file*.txt; do
  echo "${name//[![:digit:]]/}"
done
```

By contrast, if you need to work with POSIX-compatible shells (and the `file` prefix is hardcoded), consider trimming prefix and suffix using the following POSIX-compliant PEs:

```
for name in file*.txt; do
   num=${name%.txt}; num=${num#file}
   echo "$num"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
$ for f in test* ; do f=${f#test} ; echo "${f%.txt}" ; done
1
2
3
```

Add some quotes if filenames have space in them.bb

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGINFILE {
    gsub(/^test|\.txt/,"",FILENAME)
    print FILENAME
    nextfile
}' test*
1
2
3
```

Comment: Why are these better though?

Comment: The first approach given here (which I'm pretty sure was amended in during the 5-minute grace period; didn't see it when I first loaded the page) is better because it's built into the shell, as opposed to using a pipeline (which has a significant performance cost) and an external command (likewise). The latter (using `awk`), I'd argue, *isn't* better than the OP's original use of grep, except inasmuch as it's being invoked once rather than once per file. (However, this has the caveat that it can only handle a file list no longer than `ARGMAX`, less the space used for environment variables)

Comment: Better than using `grep`? They run in a single process and don't fork an external process (the `grep`) for a job that can be done within the single process.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy awk still runs in one process and doesn't fork or pipe. If the point is just to get the numbers out ie. we don't know how OP is going to use them, it's about as good as the bash?

Comment: @JamesBrown, it doesn't fork further, but *starting it in the first place* (as, since we're tagged shell, this is presumably being invoked from a shell) required a `fork()` and `execve()`.

Comment: @JamesBrown, ...and if you want to handle an arbitrarily long number of files, you'd need something more like `printf '%s\0' test*.txt | xargs -0 awk '...'` -- meaning you've got a fork for the pipeline, a fork for `xargs`, and another for each `awk` instance it hands a batch of arguments to.